# Route with parameter laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I was descriped routes.php as

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'HomeController@index');
```

And I want to use HomeController without parameter too. How to do it?

**Update:**
if url without parameter, I also want to use HomeController to display homepage, if url with parameter I want to display some data using controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters):

```
Route::get('/{id?}', 'HomeController@index');
```

> Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter, but make the presence of that route parameter optional. You may do so by placing a `?` mark after the parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

Your id will be passed as a param to the controller function

```
public function index($id) {
echo $id;

}
```

if you want to use it without params you will need a optional parameter

```
Route::get('/{id?}', 'HomeController@index');
```

change your controller function to

```
public function index($id = 0) {
    if ($id > 0 ) {
    echo $id;
    } else {
     echo "display all";
    }
    }
```

Comment: I know it, but I want to use this route without param too.